# xslt 3.0 conditional dynamic element creation

Tags: dynamic, element, xslt-3.0

I have a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="courseType" select="Record[1]/course-type"/>
```

and based on a value I would like to create a dynamic element:

```
<xsl:if test="$courseType ='B'">
    <xsl:element name="newElement">
</xsl:if>
...
other nodes
...
<xsl:if test="$courseType ='B'">
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
```

The problem is that:

The element type "xsl:element" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided much content but you can certainly use e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="other-nodes">
  ...
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$course-type = 'B'">
    <newElement>
      <xsl:sequence select="$other-nodes"/>
    </newElement>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:sequence select="$other-nodes"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Note that I have used a literal result element for `newElement` instead of using `xsl:element` as I only consider the use of `xsl:element` necessary if you want to compute the element name at run-time but it does not matter for the solution of the original problem whether you use a literal result element or `xsl:element`.